# apply function to group values while plotting (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Just wondering if it is possible to manipulable the y-axis of ggplot with geom_bar

for example:

```
library(plyr)
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(5,5,10,10,10))
df2 <- ddply(df1,.(a),sum)
ggplot(df2,aes(a,V1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

instead of aggregating df1, would it be possible to produce that plot directly in ggplot?

Comment: I don't really know what `to manipulable the y-axis of ggplot` has to do with this code.

Comment: David, what I meant is to apply a function that computes the y-axis from values that are grouped and represented on the x-axis. like the basic geom_bar counts the values, I wanted other ways of manipulating the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `stat_summary`:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(a, a)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="bar")
```

Comment: thanks Marius, exactly what I was looking for. Is there any way to keep the flexibility of geom_bar's binning ability and still to this transformation (e.g. bin first and then apply the function)?